# How to protect variables outside of the try with resources statement?

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-11

Currently at my company we received Sonarqube reviews and in one of them, there's this warning about not using `try-with-resources` statement (see below):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Socket s1 = null;
Socket s2 = null;
try {

    String host = InetAddress.getByName("myLocalHost").getHostAddress();
    int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port");
    s1 = new Socket(host, port);
    s2 = new Socket(host2, port2);
   ... }
 ...}
```

The solution to this problem might look straightforward, that is, I can wrap the Socket variables inside the `try () resources`, but in order for doing this I need to declare the host and port variables outside of the `try` statement. My concern about this solution is that the variables that are outside of this `try` statement are now unprotected in case no host or port number is given.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String host = InetAddress.getByName("myLocalHost").getHostAddress();
int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port");

try (
    Socket s1 = new Socket(host, port);
    Socket s2 = new Socket(host2, port2);
    ) {
      ....
      }
   }
```

My question is if there's a better way to protect these variables that were left outside of the `try` statement or if the approach that I am following can be enough.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Do you want to surround the declaration of `host` and `port` in a try block? Because you can just do it. Do you think you cannot have a try-with-resources inside a try block?

Comment: you can nest try-blocks if you want. but shouldn't the caller handle this situation? you don't have to squelch everything at the source. exception handling means letting the exception be raised until it's at a place that can deal with the problem.

Comment: @NathanHughes, but if I do a nested `try` then this might be redundant and as you mentioned, if no host or port is given then these errors should be handled by the exception, hence, the approach I am following should be good to go - I guess.

Comment: it would be better if the method can let the exception be thrown from it and let something higher up take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to connect immediately within the `Socket`’s constructor; you can create the instances first and connect later:

```java
try(Socket s1 = new Socket(); Socket s2 = new Socket()) {

    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("myLocalHost");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port"));
    s1.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

    InetAddress host2 = InetAddress.getByName("secondHost");
    int port2 = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port2"));
    s2.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host2, port2));

    // use the Socket
}
```

There’s no problem in closing a `Socket` that never got connected, i.e. when an exception occurred after its creation but before the `connect` call.

Note that the code above uses the resolved `InetAddress`, instead of calling `getHostAddress()` to get a string that will be resolved again during the connect operation.

By removing this redundant operation, you could also write

```java
try(Socket s1 = new Socket("myLocalHost",Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port")));
    Socket s2 = new Socket("secondHost", Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("Port2")))) {
    // use the Socket
}
```

This will resolve the name in the socket’s constructor in the first place. If an exception occurs, all resources that have been allocated so far, will be released.